# How do I fix Visual Studio 2019 warning C26052?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm creating a `.dll` in C using Visual Studio 2019.

I am using `_In_bytecount_` to help prevent buffer overflows where I can.

```
pmReportCrash(
    _In_bytecount_(_wndTitleLength * 2) LPCWCH _wndTitle,
    _In_ size_t _wndTitleLength,
    _In_bytecount_(_wndMSGLength * 2) LPCWCH _wndMSG,
    _In_ size_t _wndMSGLength,
    _In_bytecount_(_wndDescLength * 2) LPCWCH _wndDesc,
    _In_ size_t _wndDescLength,
    _In_bytecount_(_wndRestartCommandLength * 2) LPCWCH _wndRestartCommand,
    _In_ size_t _wndRestartCommandLength,
    _In_bytecount_(_wndIconDirLength * 2) LPCWCH _wndIconDir,
    _In_ size_t _wndIconDirLength,
    _In_bytecount_(_wndImageDirLength * 2) LPCWCH _wndImageDir,
    _In_ size_t _wndImageDirLength
)
```

But when I took my wide characters and passed them to `swprintf_s` as parameters:

(`swprintf_s(wndMSGParam, _wndMSGLength + 5, L"/m \"%s\"", _wndMSG);`)

It started saying this:

> Warning   C26052
>
> Potentially unconstrained access using expression '(LPCWCH)_wndMSG'
> Buffer _wndMSG is passed to function swprintf_s as unannotated
> parameter 4 None of the other parameters seem to be constrained by the
> buffer length
>
> Buffer _wndMSG is a parameter to this function declared on line 13
> Buffer is of length offset(_wndMSG)`13 + 2*_wndMSGLength`13 bytes
> [from annotation SAL_readableTo(byteCount(_wndMSGLength * 2)) at
> c:\users%userdir%\source\repos\api.postman.crashreporter\api.postman.crashreporter\postman.crash
> reporter.h(16)]
>
> Values of variables: Pointer _wndMSG is at offset 0 bytes from the
> start of the buffer Pointer result.malloc is at offset
> offset(result.malloc)`53a bytes from the start of result.malloc'53 _wndMSGLength = _wndMSGLength`13 wndMSGParam = result.malloc
>
> where offset(_wndMSG)`13 == 0 _wndMSGLength`13 >= 1     API.Postman.CrashReporter   C:\Users%userdir%\source\repos\API.Postman.CrashReporter\API.Postman.CrashReporter\PostMan.Crash
> Reporter.c    54

Is this warning possible to fix or do I need to suppress it if I want to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- The arguments do not seem to be null terminated, so you should use `%.*s` to specify a maximum length to read from `_wndMSG`.
- The size argument to `swprintf_s` should include space for the null terminator.
- The C Standard specifies that the argument type for `%s` should be a pointer to `char`, not `wchar_t`. Unless Microsoft has a different convention, you should use `%ls` for an `LPCWCH` argument.

Try using this:

```
swprintf_s(wndMSGParam, _wndMSGLength + 6, L"/m \"%.*ls\"",
           (int)_wndMSGLength, _wndMSG);
```

Notes:

- `%ls` expects a pointer to `wchar_t`, a wide character string, which is copied to the destination array unmodified.
- the `.*` in `%.*ls` specifies that a maximum number of characters to copy from the string argument is passed as an `int` argument before the string pointer. If this maximum number is a constant (eg: 10), it can be written `%.10ls` without an extra argument. Note that this *precision* field is different from the *width* field that can be written just after the `%`, as a decimal number or a `*`, and specifies the number of characters to pad the output to with spaces. For example:

  ```
  wchar_t wbuf[20];
  swprintf_s(wbuf, sizeof wbuf, L"|%10.5ls|", L"1234567");
  ```

  produces the string `|     12345|` in `wbuf`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with all of the ```swprintf_s``` arguments. What does ```"%.*ls"``` do and why does it take a int?

Comment: @Sammy: I updated the answer with explanations for the format specifier.

Comment: Thanks @chqrlie. I will use this format more often. I also found that adding ```_NullNull_terminated_``` at the beginning of each parameter also helped because now the compiler knows that the string will use a null terminator to define the end of the string.

Comment: @Sammy: it is unclear from the prototype whether these strings are actually null terminated or not.

Comment: True. How can I fix that so that you know if it's null terminated or not?

Comment: @Sammy: if `pmReportCrash` is an API you design, it is up to you to decide if the string arguments are provided as a pointer and a length or just a pointer and in the first case if the length is the actual length or a maximum length, including the null terminator or not... Whatever your choice is, make sure it is consistent with local practice and document it in the source code, both for the programmer and for the compiler to try and detect potential buffer overflows.